# Create instance of generic soapClient

Tags: c#, generics, types

Normally i would instantiate a SoapClient like this:

```
public static TestWSSoapClient Test()
{
    string endpoint = "endpoint";
    var soapClient = new TestWSSoapClient(endpoint);

    return soapClient;
}
```

But i'd like to use a more generic approach:

```
public static ICommunicationObject SoapClient<TSoap>()
{
    string endpoint = "endpoint";
    var soapClient = new TSoap(endpoint);

    return soapClient;
}
```

But obviously you cannot create an instance like that from a generic type. How can i create this instance and still pass the `endpoint` string to it?

Comment: Do all your TSoaps have a common base class?

Comment: @nvoigt Not a custom base class. But they all have `ClientBase<TChannel>` which is a default base class that the Service Reference generates. I think i need to do something with that class though, since that is the one that expects a constructor with an argument.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451336/how-to-pass-parameters-to-activator-createinstancet duplicate?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Almost, unfortunately it is not as easy as that. I need to create an instance of `TestSoapClient` which has an abstract base class `ClientBase<TChannel>`. I need to create an instance of that in a generic way.

Comment: You cant just use ChannelFactory<T>?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Wow, didn't know that existed... But thanks, this is way better than what i was trying :) Can you post that as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static T GetChannel<T>(Binding binding, EndpointAddress address)
{
    var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, address);
    var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

    return channel;
}

var binding = BindingFactory.GetBindingX();
var address = new EndpointAddress("endpoint");

Program.GetChannel<IMyInterface>(binding, address);

channel.DoStuff(parameters);
```