# XML Import Class Name

Tags: c#, xml, class, import

Here's my XML:

```
<slot01>Blaster</slot01>
```

How do I parse this so Blaster (as a **class** name, NOT a string) gets added to a list such as:

`List<IWeapon> weapon = new List<IWeapon>();
weapon.Add(new Blaster());`

Note: my other variables are set using:

```
case "name": setName.Add(childList[k].InnerText.ToString()); break;
```

Am I missing a cast? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Using reflection or using a factory, try searching.

Comment: Nope, sorry, I don't see the code I require. Plus I'm not using an abstract class.

Comment: Then perhaps read harder, it might be hidden in plain sight: `Activator.CreateInstance()`.

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance()` is permanently red... monodevelop hates it. - never mind, needed to add Using System;

Comment: "Permanently red" is not an adequate problem description that we can do anything about. Perhaps consider updating your question with your current code and the actual compiler messages.

Comment: Next headache...how do I pass variables using this? It seems to only accept the default constructor (which works by the way).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451336/how-to-pass-parameters-to-activator-createinstancet