# How to Pass Parameters to Activator.CreateInstance(string, string)

Tags: c#, reflection, activator, createinstance

I need to create an object of a specific type.

The only clue i have on this type is a string (coming from a text file) and the assembly where i can find this object.

All the constructors of all the objects in this assembly have the same constructor signature, let's say :

```
public MyObject(object o)
{}
```

How can i pass this parameter to the constructor using Activator.CreateInstance (string assemblyName, string, className) ?

Comment: This post give you the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451336/how-to-pass-parameters-to-activator-createinstancet

Comment: Actually no, i have seen it and read it before posting my question...the difference is, in my case, i dont know the target type specificly, i only have a string to "reflect"

Comment: ... on this site, people consider "duplicate question" far too easily.... i copy paste the title of the so-called "duplicated question".... on purpose.... hoping that people will see how it is diferent. After few hours i have found a way to solve my problem.. a way which is not explain in the so called "duplicated question"... and i can't post it here and help the community with it.  Please consider unmarked it so i can answer to my post pls

Comment: @G.Dealmeida: Could you post your answer here in the comments. I seemed to face a similar situation here. Thanks!