# MVC Cloning Controller Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having some problem to implement a clonable version of the `ControllerContext`. I need this because i'm trying to cache it and access it later in a part of my system that can't access this information and i can't pass it as a parameter. This is what i have achieved:

```
public class ControllerContextClonable : ControllerContext, ICloneable
{
    public object Clone()
    {
        var cloneContext = (ControllerContext)MemberwiseClone();

        return cloneContext;
    }

    public static List<ControllerContextClonable> ToList( ControllerContextClonable context )
    {
        return new List<ControllerContextClonable>{ context };
    }
}
```

The problem is: When i'm caching it, i have the `ControllerContext` but i need to pass to my caching method a `ControllerContextClonable` object. How can i convert my `ControllerContext` to `ControllerContextClonable` ? This is how i'm trying to pass it and the caching methods:

```
//If i try to call my method with the safe convertion i get a null object
CacheMethods.SetContextCache( context as ControllerContextClonable );

public static void SetContextCache( ControllerContextClonable context, string cacheKey = "SiteContext" )
{
    CacheList<ControllerContextClonable>.RemoveCache( cacheKey );
    CacheList<ControllerContextClonable>.Add( new List<ControllerContextClonable> { context } );
    CacheList<ControllerContextClonable>.CacheIt( cacheKey );
}

public static ControllerContextClonable GetCachedContext( string cacheKey = "SiteContext" )
{
    CacheList<ControllerContextClonable>.LoadCached( cacheKey );

    if( CacheList<ControllerContextClonable>.LoadCached( cacheKey ) )
    {
        return CacheList<ControllerContextClonable>.DataList.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return null;
}
```

How can i correctly convert the executing `ControllerContext` to my `ControllerContextClonable` class to be used on the cache ? Also if i'm doing this wrong could anyone point me the right way ?

**EDIT:**

I'm going to explain my workaround: I'm creating a template parsing system where it will parse a template using a tag system, in this tag the user will provide the `ViewModel` class and the template `View` he wishes to use.

Having that i will instantiate this `ViewModel` using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35996758/3228150) code to do it. This code doesn't let me pass a controllercontext as a parameter, i tried to modify it to accept the parameter but it would give me an `Common language runtime detected an invalid program` error.

Now the problem, on this certain case i have a ViewModel that needs to fetch information that was saved on a `ViewBag` using my `Filter`. The only solution i could think of was cache the context and access it but i'm failing on the convertion part. Could i solve this any other way ? What i need is to access the `Context` inside some methods that are called by my `ViewModel` constructor.

This is the `ViewModel`:

```
public class LanguageTestViewModel
{
    //Properties

    public LanguageTestViewModel() { Initialize( "", "", 0 ); }

    public LanguageTestViewModel( string where, string order, int take ) { Initialize( where, order, take ); }

    private void Initialize( string where, string order, int take )
    {
        var Context = CacheMethods.GetCachedContext();
        var EList   = HelperMethods.CreateSelectListItem( "SELECT A STATE", Context );
        var States  = CacheMethods.GetStatesForm( Context );

        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I have to change my storage method since i'm using `HttpRuntime.Cache`, which is a shared storage and i can't storage context information on that can change based on user, device, location, etc.. Said that i need this information on a `per-user` storage. Any ideas ?

Comment: I suspect your actual problem is that you are trying to cache this object in the first place. Perhaps there is a better solution if you would describe the "later part of your application" that is using this context and why you can't pass it directly. If this is a cross-cutting concern, a better approach would be to use an [MVC filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx), which is context-aware, rather than trying to stuff the context into a part of the application where it doesn't belong.

Comment: @NightOwl888, i have added more information about the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you. Clone the controller instance and then you have access to the objects.Notice I am using `HomeController` that implements `IControllerContextClonable`. This example is the simplest solution. But it works. Eg.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller, IControllerContextClonable
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var controller = (HomeController) this.MemberwiseClone();
            var list = ToList(controller);

            return View();
        }

        public List<IControllerContextClonable> ToList(IControllerContextClonable context)
        {

            return new List<IControllerContextClonable> { context};
        }
    }    

    public interface IControllerContextClonable
    {
        List<IControllerContextClonable> ToList(IControllerContextClonable context);    
    }
}
```

Output. ControllerContext instance is nicely hydrated.

[image]

The `SetContextCache` method will have the signature as below. Notice the parameter type is `IControllerContextClonable`. This way `SetContextCache`method will accept any type that implements `IControllerContextClonable`

```
public static void SetContextCache(IControllerContextClonable context, string cacheKey = "SiteContext" )
{
    CacheList<IControllerContextClonable>.RemoveCache( cacheKey );
    CacheList<IControllerContextClonable>.Add( new List<IControllerContextClonable> { context} );
    CacheList<IControllerContextClonable>.CacheIt( cacheKey );
}
```

You can then pass any instance of a type(a class) that implements IControllerContextClonable as below.This is valid because `HomeController` implements IControllerContextClonable. You have access to the object and you can manipulate it as you desire.

e.g.

```
  var homeController = new HomeController();

  CacheMethods.SetContextCache(homeController);
```

Comment: Thank you for this but i just realized that i can't work with my `CacheMethods` since they use `HttpRuntime,Cache`, which is a shared information and i need a `per-user storage`, like sessions and cookies, for this kind of information.

Comment: Yes,  for that purpose, you would need to use unique user sessions or cookies

Comment: I accepted your answer as correct since you solved my cloning problem. I managed to make the ControllerContext work as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, you can also make the ControllerContext  as your parameter. Glad you are happy